# Can an ASP.NET worker thread handle multiple requests at once?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I know that ASP.NET will execute a request on a single thread from a pool.  Is the inverse true? Will a single ASP.NET request exclusively hold a worker thread until the request completes, or will ASP.NET re-use the same thread between multiple concurrent requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even your first statement is not entirely true.

ASP.NET can exhibit *thread agility* - different parts of a request's lifecycle can (in some cases - usually if some requests are long-running, I believe, or if you're responding asynchronously) run in different threads. See [this article](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20071107094255/http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html)) for more information. Unfortunately I haven't seen very much in the way of clear, unambiguous and authoritative documentation on this topic :(

Comment: Yes, but it should be mentioned that it only happens if you do it explicitly, which in turn requires Async="true" insite the <%Page%> tag.

Comment: Nope, I've seen this happen without explicitly using async. I used the "technique" mentioned in the linked article - long sleeps.

Comment: Great links, thanks.  According to this, it will switch on some long-running requests or under heavy traffic without any explicit action by the developer. The HTTPContext is transferred but ThreadStatic values are not, which is mostly what I was wondering about.

Comment: @flatline: That's mightily convenient, that by not actually answering your question, I happened to answer what you were really after ;)