# How Asp.NET Handle Multiple Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I was wondering how Asp.NET handles multiple requests ? E.g : When 1000 users request a page from an Asp.net installed web server, are they queued and handled in order or is there any other way to simultaneously handle those requests ?

I found some articles but they were too deep and long, I need a couple of quick answers to my question?

Thank you very much.

**Edit :**

I was reading Threads in a C# book and I wondered how asp.net handles multiple requests. Is it creating a thread for each requests or putting them into a queue for later handling or any way else?

Comment: If you need a quick answer, can you tell us why you need to know this? Are you worried about thread safety? Performance? The gist of it is that a number (probly less than 1000) threads handle a number of request simultaneously, and the rest of the requests get queued. When the queue gets full, the web server starts rejecting requests.

Comment: I put some extra text above, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aaron, you may want to check out these Stack Overflow posts:

- [Is ASP.NET multithreaded (how does it execute requests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435492)
- [Can an ASP.NET worker thread handle multiple requests at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456352/)

I think that both the questions and the answers of the above posts may resolve your query.

Comment: Yeah but the blog post address they said on that link is dead.

Comment: Internet archive to the rescue...
http://web.archive.org/web/20071107094255/http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html

Comment: Thanks spender :) ... Aaron, I've added another related post in my answer, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your great help.